# Прикрепить файл к задачи в OpenProject API v3

Tags: php, laravel, api, guzzle

Нужно прикрепить файл к задаче проекта в OpenProject Api v3. Использую Laravel и Guzzle последней версии.

```
$openProjectIssue = json_decode($this->client->post('projects/' . $projectData[0] . '/work_packages', $data)->getBody()->getContents());

        foreach ($request->allFiles()['files'] as $file) {
            $data = [
                'headers' => [
                    'Content-Type' => 'multipart/form-data',
                    'Accept' => 'multipart/form-data',
                ],
                'body' => json_encode([
                    '_type' => 'Attachment',
                    'contentType' => $file->getMimeType(),
                    'fileName' => $file->getRealPath(),
                    'description' => [
                        'format' => 'plain',
                        'html' => '<p>' . $file->getClientOriginalName() . '</p>',
                        'raw' => $file->getClientOriginalName(),
                    ],
                    'filesize' => $file->getSize(),
                ])
            ];

            try {
                $openProjectIssue = json_decode($this->client->post('work_packages/' . $openProjectIssue->id . '/attachments', $data)->getBody()->getContents());
                dd($openProjectIssue);
            } catch (\Exception $exception) {
                dd(json_decode($exception->getResponse()->getBody()->getContents(), true));
            }
        }
```

Ссылка на документацию: https://www.openproject.org/docs/api/endpoints/attachments/

Хотя я пробовал и через collections как в примере по теме:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51251894/how-to-get-an-attachments-data-with-the-openproject-api

Comment: Простите забыл указать ошибки :
  "errorIdentifier" => "urn:openproject-org:api:v3:errors:MultipleErrors"
  "message" => "Для нескольких полей были нарушены ограничения."

        "_type" => "Error"
        "errorIdentifier" => "urn:openproject-org:api:v3:errors:PropertyConstraintViolation"
        "message" => "Файл не может быть пустым."
        "_type" => "Error"
        "errorIdentifier" => "urn:openproject-org:api:v3:errors:PropertyConstraintViolation"
        "message" => "Тип содержимого файла не может быть пустым."

Comment: Вы проверяли, что возвращает `$file->getMimeType()`

Comment: Да -> image/png

Comment: для всех файлов в цикле?

Comment: Конечно. Проблема в другом, не правильно составлен запрос и я не понимаю что ему не хватает.

Comment: $data = [
                'multipart' => [
                    [
                        'name' => 'file',
                        'contents' => Psr7\Utils::tryFopen($pathToFile, 'r'),
                    ],
                    [
                        'name' => 'filename',
                        'contents' => $file->getClientOriginalName(),
                    ]
                ],
            ];

Пробую уже так. Жалуется на filename уже

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте взять функцию формирования мультипарт [отсюда](https://gist.github.com/ssigwart/83c394fb689d4797ffc3) и использовать в Вашем коде. Если я не ошибся, то должно быть так:

```html
<?php
$contentType = '';
foreach ($request->allFiles()['files'] as $file) {
  $body['metadata'] = json_encode([
                    '_type' => 'Attachment',
                    'contentType' => $file->getMimeType(),
                    'fileName' => $file->getClientOriginalName(),
                    'description' => [
                        'format' => 'plain',
                        'html' => '<p>' . $file->getClientOriginalName() . '</p>',
                        'raw' => $file->getClientOriginalName(),
                    ],
                    'filesize' => $file->getSize(),
                ]);
  $files['file'] = $file->getRealPath();
  $data['body'] = buildMultipartFormData($body, $files, $contentType);
  $data['headers'] => [
                'Content-Type' => $contentType,
            ];
  
  try {
    $openProjectIssue = json_decode($this->client->post('work_packages/' . $openProjectIssue->id . '/attachments', $data)->getBody()->getContents());
    dd($openProjectIssue);
  } catch (\Exception $exception) {
    dd(json_decode($exception->getResponse()->getBody()->getContents(), true));
  }
}
```

Comment: К сожалению не вышло, функция конвертирует все тело в json. Пробую через multipart

Comment: не увидел что функция не формирует заголовка. Подправил код добавив хедер

Comment: Сейчас я пробую вот так:
`
        foreach ($request->allFiles()['files'] as $file) {
            $pathToFile = $file->getRealPath();

            $data = [
                'multipart' => [
                    [
                        'name' => 'file',
                        'contents' => Psr7\Utils::tryFopen($pathToFile, 'r'),
                        'filename' => $file->getClientOriginalName(),
                    ],
                ],
            ];

отправка
`

Comment: суть в том, в теле запроса должно быть две порции данных: 
1) metadata - которая содержит json-строку с описанием 
2) file - само содержимое файла

Comment: хмм, окей, сейчас попробую

Comment: Да, сработало. Просто в шоке. Огромное спасибо, даже не знаю как отблагодарить. Не знаю сталкивался ли ты с этой проблемой до этого, но решение сработало.

Comment: c Guzzle должен еще проще вариант прокатить. Ниже добавлю ответ, можете попробовать

П.С. А с OpenProject никогда не работал. Просто документация дала ответ

Answer (score 1):

```html
<?php

foreach ($request->allFiles()['files'] as $file) {  
  $data = [
    'multipart' => [
        [
            'name'     => 'metadata',
            'contents' => json_encode([
                '_type' => 'Attachment',
                'contentType' => $file->getMimeType(),
                'fileName' => $file->getClientOriginalName(),
                'description' => [
                    'format' => 'plain',
                    'html' => '<p>' . $file->getClientOriginalName() . '</p>',
                    'raw' => $file->getClientOriginalName(),
                ],
                'filesize' => $file->getSize(),
            ]);
        ],
        [
            'name'     => 'file',
            'contents' => \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Utils::tryFopen($file->getRealPath(), 'r'),
            'filename' => $file->getClientOriginalName()
        ],
    ]
  ];
  
  try {
    $openProjectIssue = json_decode($this->client->post('work_packages/' . $openProjectIssue->id . '/attachments', $data)->getBody()->getContents());
    dd($openProjectIssue);
  } catch (\Exception $exception) {
    dd(json_decode($exception->getResponse()->getBody()->getContents(), true));
  }
}
```

Comment: Да, это тоже работает. Спасибо за ответ